# How to write a Blogger widget sorting the post list by alphanumeric order?

Tags: json, blogger

Hello I wrote the following code as widget to my blog (Blogger), however I need an alphanumeric sort of the posts instead the newest first. Can anyone help me?

```
<div id="hlrpsb">
<script style="text/javascript" src="http://helplogger.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/recent-posts-with-titles-only.js"></script>
<script style="text/javascript">
var numposts = 10;
var showpostdate = false;
var showpostsummary = false;
var standardstyling = true;
</script>
<script src="http://myblogaddress.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showrecentposts"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some research in this area and not able to sort the posts other than published date. To sort alphabetically needs to write custom code. Anyway feed it is giving us recent entries only so sorting based on alphabet will not give proper sequence of all the posts.